# How to let minted highlight a whole file from disk

Tags: minted, python

I am using the `minted` package to highlight source code in LaTeX. It works well for a piece of code embedded in `\begin{minted} ... \end{minted}`. Now the question is if it is possible to highlight a whole file whose path is specified in `.tex`. Going further, is it possible to let `minted` to choose an appropriated `lexer` to use in according to the suffix of a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote the manual:

> Finally, there’s the comment `\inputminted` command to read and format whole
>   files. Its syntax is `\inputminted[options]{language}{filename}`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... Do you have any idea about my last question?

Comment: @SoftTimur Sorry, no, if I did I would have said so. I've never used `minted`.

Comment: @SoftTimur: You could try to be clever with the `\IfEndWith` command of [`xstring`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/generic/xstring/xstring_doc_en.pdf) or something like that, if you really can't select the lexer yourself every time.